# not able to write a spark DF as a parquert file error:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, json4s

Not able to write a spark DF as a parquet file.

> Error:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.render$default$2(Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;)Lorg/json4s/Formats;

- spark version 2.4.0
- scala version : 2.11.8

code:

```
val deltaTableInput1=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").option("inferSchema","true").load("path") // this is fine

deltaTableInput1.write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("path")
```

error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods$.render$default$2(Lorg/json4s/JsonAST$JValue;)Lorg/json4s/Formats;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType.json(DataType.scala:67)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetWriteSupport$.setSchema(ParquetWriteSupport.scala:445)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat.prepareWrite(ParquetFileFormat.scala:111)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:159)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:78)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:125)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:73)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:668)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:276)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:270)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:228)
  ... 49 elided
```

Comment: How do you start the Spark app? You can use `spark.range(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("parquet").save("path")` instead to focus on parquet issue only. Any reason to use spark version 2.4.0?

Comment: For reading hbase using spark, Another one with 2.4.4 and custom scala 2.12 i being used for kafka integration

Comment: How do you start the Spark app?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two different versions if `json4s` in your installation. Please remove the databricks dependency, as you don't need it. You can directly read csv file in spark:

```
val deltaTableInput1=spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","|").option("inferSchema","true").csv("path")
```

And then write to parquet:

```
deltaTableInput1.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("path")
```

I have tested the above with spark 2.4.0 and it is working fine.

Comment: Can you share your json 4s version's. I have 3.2.10 ast,core,jackson,est and scala alone is 3.5.3

Comment: I have only 4 jars corresponding to jackson4s with version 3.5.3 for ast, core, jackson and scalap which comes with `spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` package.

Comment: i added 3.2.10 instead of 3.5.3 due to hbase integration issue

Comment: That's why you are getting the error. I tried with `3.2.10` and got error while writing to parquet. Change it to `3.5.3` and then try again.

Answer (score 0):

I am suspecting may be due to datatype

While reading data from csv format file,please disable Inferschema ( set as false) and instead use custom schema with your expected data types  by using .schema method . Then write the DF in parquet format.

Please try this once and let me know